# Text on HTML5 Canvas loop

Tags: html, loops, text, canvas

I have code here that displays the days of the week horizontally. How can I make it so that it is displayed in a **for loop** horizontally but also taking into account the size of the canvas? (the size of the canvas in this case is 600)

```
canvasObj1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
context = canvasObj1.getContext('2d');

context.fillStyle = "#5D6C7B"; 
context.font = "12px sans-serif"; 
context.fillText("Monday", 10, 225); 
context.fillText("Tuesday", 70, 225); 
context.fillText("Wednesday", 130, 225); 
context.fillText("Thursday", 210, 225); 
context.fillText("Friday", 275, 225); 
context.fillText("Saturday", 330, 225); 
context.fillText("Sunday", 400, 225);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in a for loop" -- animation? Please describe you need better :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do it:

**[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/t79rN/)**

```
// put week names in an array
var days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
            'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
    gap = 5,  // gap between the names
    x = 0,    // for drawing text
    w = 0,    // for measuring total width
    i = 0;    // generic counter

context.fillStyle = "#5D6C7B";
context.font = "12px sans-serif";

// calc total width incl. gaps
for (; i < days.length; i++) {
    w += (context.measureText(days[i]).width + gap);
}

// fine adjust width removing last gap and adding a couple of pixels for space
w = w - gap + 2;

// adjust scale
context.scale(canvas.width / w, 1);

// draw the texts
for (i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    context.fillText(days[i], x, 225);
    x += (context.measureText(days[i]).width + gap);
}
```

Just remember to reset the scale or use it to draw other elements relative to texts. One other thing you can do is to store the calculated positions to another array so you can use that with for example vertical lines and so forth.

Another way, in case there is space for all text, is to calculate the total width of the text only (not using the gap value), then subtract it from canvas width, divide on 6 to get an average gap value which you then use with the draw loop.